# How can joinToString on a cloned ArrayList throw ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: kotlin, collections, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I have an ArrayList of Strings, which is constantly changed (adding and removing lines) by a non-UI thread.
In the UI I want to show the current content of that ArrayList in a simple TextView.

When preparing the text for the TextView by joinToString("\n"), I was immediately receiving a ConcurrentModificationException, which was not very surprising.

So, to avoid that, I cloned the ArrayList, before joining it to a String:

```
val textLines = globalTextLineArray.clone() as ArrayList<String>
myTextView.text = textLines.joinToString("\n")
```

What I am not understanding is, that even now I am receiving from time to time a ConcurrentModificationException.

How can that happen?

The  StackTrace is:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:866)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.joinTo(_Collections.kt:3341)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.joinToString(_Collections.kt:3361)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.joinToString$default(_Collections.kt:3360)
    at MyActivity.updateTextInView(MyActivity.kt:79)
    at MyActivity.access$updateTextInView(MyActivity.kt:24)
    at MyActivity$textViewUpdater$1.run(MyActivity.kt:85)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

There may be better ways to achieve what I am trying to do (e.g. using a thread-safe collection). But still I would like to understand, why the cloning attempt does not work.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace for the CME that gets thrown when you use `clone`?

Comment: The stack trace in my post is the one, that appears after I have cloned the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not locking anything, so `clone` on the UI thread is executed at the same time as `remove`/`add` on the other thread. The code could be run in any order. This is bad, because you could cloning an array list that is *in the middle of removing an element* - in an intermediate, invalid state. When you try to iterate on that incorrectly cloned object, the iterator is confused and thinks you are modifying it concurrently.

In short, `ArrayList` is not thread safe. It does not make any guarantees. You seem to understand that `joinToString` isn't thread safe. Well, `clone` isn't either, and neither is `add` or `remove`.

To illustrate how this can happen, let's assume you're using [OpenJDK 11](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java). The `ArrayList.remove` method, among other things, decrease the `size` field:

```
// line 670
final int newSize;
if ((newSize = size - 1) > i)
    System.arraycopy(es, i + 1, es, i, newSize - i);
es[size = newSize] = null; // updates size field
```

Now let's look at what `clone` does:

```
// line 373
public Object clone() {
    try {
        ArrayList<?> v = (ArrayList<?>) super.clone();
        v.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
        v.modCount = 0;
        return v;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
        throw new InternalError(e);
    }
}
```

Let's try to contrive a situation that will cause an invalid array list to be cloned.

First, it calls `super.clone`. Imagine that this happens before `size = newSize`, so the old size before the removal gets cloned. Then, `clone` calls `Arrays.copyOf` to copy the internal array. Note that in this line, it accesses `size` again. Imagine that this time, the access is done *after* `size = newSize`, so we get the new smaller `size`. What we have now is an array list with `size > elementData.length`!

What happens when you iterate over this? The iterator `Itr` implemented like this:

```
// line 990
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

It will keep iterator until `cursor == size`,and note how in `next`, it checks for `i >= elementData.length`. Remember that our `size` is one more than `elementData.length`, so this condition will eventually be satisfied.

---

When you modify the array list, you should lock it, and when you clone it or join it to string, you should also lock it.